# Java Integer changing back the second after it changes

Tags: java

My code,

```
int selection = 0;
            if(checkKey(Keyboard.KEY_Z)){
                selection++;
                System.out.println(selection);
            }
            if(checkKey(Keyboard.KEY_B)){
                selection--;
                System.out.println(selection);
            }
```

Does not appear to be functioning correctly. The integer selection seems to be changing back to 0 almost immediately after it is changed by the key function.

Heres the code surrounding it which is relevant

```
int selection = 0;
            if(checkKey(Keyboard.KEY_Z)){
                selection++;
                System.out.println(selection);
            }
            else if(checkKey(Keyboard.KEY_B)){
                selection--;
                System.out.println(selection);
            }
            if(selection < 14){
                selection = 1;
            }
            if(selection == -1){
                selection = 14;
            }
            if(Toggles.clickMenu){
                if(selection == 1){
                    var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "b<", 62, 34, 0000);
                    if(this.mc.gameSettings.Enter.isPressed()){
                        Toggles.fly = !Toggles.fly;
                    }
                }else if(selection == 2.0){
                    var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "b<", 62, 46, 0000);
                    if(this.mc.gameSettings.Enter.isPressed()){
                        Toggles.sprint = !Toggles.sprint;
                    }
                }else if(selection == 3){
                    var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "b<", 62, 58, 0000);
                    if(this.mc.gameSettings.Enter.isPressed()){
                        Toggles.autojump = !Toggles.autojump;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here is even further out code:

```
if(Toggles.clickMenu2){
                Gui.drawRect(85, 200, 161, 0, 0xaa000000);
                var8.drawStringWithShadow("Menu2", 90, 4, 0x00ff00);
                if(Toggles.off == true){
                    var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "bSpeedMeUp", 87, 16, 0000);
                }else{
                    var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "bSpeedMeUp", 87, 16, 0000);
                }
//              if(Toggles.off == true){
//                  var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "b[=]", 144, 16, 0000);
//              }else{
//                  var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "b[=]", 144, 16, 0000);
//              }
                if(Toggles.mute == true){
                    var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "bGoFancy", 87, 28, 0000);
                }else{
                    var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "bGoFancy", 87, 28, 0000);
                }
//              if(Toggles.mute == true){
//                  var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "b[-]", 144, 28, 0000);
//              }else{
//                  var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "b[-]", 144, 28, 0000);
//              }
                if(Toggles.noweather){
                    var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "aNoWeather", 87, 40, 0000);
                }else{
                    var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "cNoWeather", 87, 40, 0000);
                }
//              if(Toggles.noweather){
//                  var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "a[F9]", 144, 40, 0000);
//              }else{
//                  var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "c[F9]", 144, 40, 0000);
//              }
                if(Toggles.spider){
                    var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "aSpider", 87, 52, 0000);
                    //var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "a[F8]", 144, 52, 0000);
                }else{
                    var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "cSpider", 87, 52, 0000);
                    //var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "c[F8]", 144, 52, 0000);
                }
                if(Toggles.step){
                    var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "aStep", 87, 64, 0000);
                    //var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "a[F7]", 144, 64, 0000);
                }else{
                    var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "cStep", 87, 64, 0000);
                    //var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "c[F7]", 144, 64, 0000);
                }
            }else{
                    Gui.drawRect(85, 16, 161, 0, 0xaa000000);
                    var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "cMenu2", 90, 4, 0x00ff00);

            }
            //THE UI! **** YES! IFNDAISGOFJOOHASF
            if(checkKey(Keyboard.KEY_Z)){
                selection++;
                System.out.println(selection);
            }
            else if(checkKey(Keyboard.KEY_B)){
                selection--;
                System.out.println(selection);
            }
            if(selection < 14){
                selection = 1;
            }
            if(selection == -1){
                selection = 14;
            }
            if(Toggles.clickMenu){
                if(selection == 1){
                    var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "b<", 62, 34, 0000);
                    if(this.mc.gameSettings.Enter.isPressed()){
                        Toggles.fly = !Toggles.fly;
                    }
                }else if(selection == 2.0){
                    var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "b<", 62, 46, 0000);
                    if(this.mc.gameSettings.Enter.isPressed()){
                        Toggles.sprint = !Toggles.sprint;
                    }
                }else if(selection == 3){
                    var8.drawStringWithShadow(Strings.textsymbol + "b<", 62, 58, 0000);
                    if(this.mc.gameSettings.Enter.isPressed()){
                        Toggles.autojump = !Toggles.autojump;
                    }
                }
            }
            //KeyChecker
            String actionsound = "random.levelup";
            String symbol = "§";
            if(this.mc.gameSettings.eClientMenu1.isPressed()){
                Toggles.clickMenu = !Toggles.clickMenu;
            }
            if(this.mc.gameSettings.eClientMenu2.isPressed()){
                Toggles.clickMenu2 = !Toggles.clickMenu2;
            }

            if(this.mc.gameSettings.eClientFly.isPressed()){
                Toggles.fly = !Toggles.fly;
                if(Toggles.fly == true){
                    mc.thePlayer.addChatMessage(new ChatComponentText(Strings.textsymbol + "aFly is now enabled")); 
                }else{
                    mc.thePlayer.addChatMessage(new ChatComponentText(Strings.textsymbol + "cFly is now disabled")); 
                }

                mc.theWorld.playSound(mc.thePlayer.posX+0.5D, mc.thePlayer.posY+0.5D, mc.thePlayer.posZ+0.5D, actionsound, 10.3F, 10.6F, false);
            }
```

CheckKey Codes:

```
public GuiIngame(Session p_i1103_1_, Minecraft p_i1036_1_) {
        this.session = p_i1103_1_;
        String username = p_i1103_1_.getUsername();
        keyStates = new boolean [256];
        this.mc = p_i1036_1_;
        this.persistantChatGUI = new GuiNewChat(p_i1036_1_);
        this.field_152127_m = new GuiStreamIndicator(this.mc);
    }
    public boolean checkKey(int i){
        if(mc.currentScreen != null){
            return false;
        }

        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(i) != keyStates[i]){
            return keyStates[i] = !keyStates[i];
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe both `if`s are being entered.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted `else if`?

Comment: How do you know it's changing back? What method are you using to check the value of `selection`?

Comment: Is that a local variable?

Comment: Well, checkKey should only return true if I'm hitting that key, but I'll remove one of the checkKeys and see if it works out.

Comment: Still goes back to 0. :I

Comment: This question lacks a lot of context for anything useful to come out of it. You're not saying where you get that 0 or what's around that code.

Comment: You might want to consider creating a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: is it even being incremented?

Comment: Yes, it is being incremented/decremented, but then it goes back to 0.

Comment: So, you're saying if you set a break point on the output statement after it's correctly getting incremented the debugger confims `selection==1`. Then, at a break point set here `if(selection < 14)` reveals `selection==0`! You've got yourself a broken version of Java I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

Well, both conditions must be returning true. The block of the first condition increments the selection variable and the block of the second condition decrements it.

If you wish only one condition to be entered (at most), you should use else if :

```
        int selection = 0;
        if(checkKey(Keyboard.KEY_Z)){
            selection++;
            System.out.println(selection);
        }
        else if(checkKey(Keyboard.KEY_B)){
            selection--;
            System.out.println(selection);
        }
```

Comment: It still stays at the same number... odd

Comment: @WhatTheFruit Can you show us the full code then?

Comment: @WhatTheFruit What about the code of `checkKey`?

Comment: Posting that - Have had no trouble with it in the past.